# Enumerate or Count Rows JOIN MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables, `task` and `step`.

Example of the `task` table

```
^ TaskID  ^ OperID  ^ StepID  ^ Status    ^
| 10      | 10      | 10      | Finished  |
| 11      | 10      | 20      | Active    |
| 12      | 20      | 10      | Active    |
| 13      | 30      | 10      | Finished  |
| 14      | 40      | 10      | Finished  |
| 15      | 10      | 30      | Finished  |
| 16      | 30      | 20      | Active    |
| 17      | 40      | 20      | Active    |
| 18      | 10      | 40      | Active    |
| 19      | 30      | 30      | Active    |
```

Example of the `step` table.

```
^ StepID  ^ StepName  ^
| 10       | Step1     |
| 20       | Step2     |
| 30       | Step3     |
| 40       | Step4     |
```

I want to enumerate Active StepName from Task, grouped by OperID, in other words, i need an output like this.

```
^ OperID  ^ StepName  ^ OrderID  ^
| 10      | Step2     | 1       |
| 10      | Step3     | 2       |
| 10      | Step4     | 3       |
| 20      | Step1     | 1       |
| 30      | Step2     | 1       |
| 30      | Step2     | 2       |
| 40      | Step2     | 1       |
```

I read in [another article](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group) about Session Variables, but i can't make it work.

```
SELECT
   T.OperID,
   S.StepName,
   @Order := IF(@StepName = S.StepName, @Order + 1, 1) AS 'Order',
   @StepName := S.StepName 
FROM
   task AS T
   INNER JOIN step AS S ON S.StepID = T.StepID
WHERE T.Status = 'Active'
ORDER BY OperID
```

Here is some SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71316/2

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Query edited because of error (thanks to Marc B), but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the wrong thing:

```
@Order := IF(@Order = S.StepName, @Order + 1, 1) AS 'Order',
             ^^^^^---should probably be @StepName
```

Right now you're comparing the integer value you're building up against the string in "StepName'.